# Do employers look at quitting a job in order to shift career paths to be a developer good or bad?

Tags: career-development, job-change, developer

I want to give a quick timeline to help everyone understand where I am at in my career:

2010 - Graduated with Psychology degree (bad idea)

2011 - Worked at a company for 2 years as software technical support.

2013 - Same company, different job as a VERY Junior Software engineer (C# developer, and I did not know a lick of C# yet).

2014 - Company was bought, and I was laid off. I then tried to get another developer position, and quickly found out that I had no book knowledge and didn't know how to interview for developer positions.

2015 - Just a few months after this, I ended up getting a backend support/jr DBA-type role at a company.  I work extremely long hours, nights and weekends, and am never really off work (not to mention the pay is bad).  I don't mind occassional work as such, but it is the norm now.

2016 - I am planning on quitting my job for a few months (2-3), to be able to:

1. Move to a different state, where my wife's family lives.  Also our lease is up, so it's a convenient time
2. Study and create applications I can learn and practice with, and be able to show employers
3. Switch career paths and go full on C# developer again.

Is this a good idea or a bad idea for my career?  Why or why not?  I am confident I can get my skills/knowledge where I need to be in 2-3 months, but am unsure if my time spent studying and practicing will be frowned upon.

Thank you!!

Comment: Its a great idea for your career. Though i believe your underestimating the time you will need for this, its great that you have some prior experience but it sounds like you'll be having a lot of distractions around you which will likely slow you down, i took the path you're currently considering and i don't look back. Took me 6 months from complete scratch to learn C# and the first interview i had i breezed. by no definition was it easy though, the hardest thing for me while teaching my self was gauging how good or bad i was because i had nothing to compare my experience to...

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  I am doing what I can to prep now, but I have 2 months and then am moving out of state.  I've decided to do as much as I can now, and hopefully that will lessen the gap of unemployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a good idea or a bad idea for my career? Why or why not?

If you are really confident that you would use that time very productively, and come back with enhanced skills for the job, then go ahead and take a learning break.

> but am unsure if my time spent studying and practicing will be frowned
>   upon

It is frowned upon if you don't show significant improvement after the learning phase. Else, it is highly appreciated that you chose to spend dedicated time for improving your skills for your career.

So, go ahead and do it! However, don't hop jobs after your learning break. It **is** frowned upon.

Comment: Thank you!  I want to take a learning break so I don't have to jump into another job I don't like.  I am definitely trying to avoid job hopping.  I want to prep for a career, and a company I can get behind.

I will have to move/quit in 2 months, so until then, I am going to work my butt off to prep as much as possible, to minimize the time I will be unemployed.  In about a month, I'm thinking of applying for a few jobs here and there, to gauge where I am at in my learning process.  And it wouldn't hurt to find something before I move, if it aligns with my goals.

Comment: @Robman24 Then, I would advise you to go ahead and take that break, if you think you can pull it off productively, as it'd help your career a great deal :)